# Alembic migrations in ormar not working (FastAPI)

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, fastapi, python-3.9, ormar

I want to migrate through Alembic, but something doesn't work. I don't understand what exactly I'm doing wrong.

My alembic .env

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool
from db import ORMAR_DATABASE_URL
from alembic import context
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
config = context.config

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

from db import Base
target_metadata = Base.metadata
URL = "postgresql://admin:admin@localhost/fa_naesmi"



def run_migrations_offline():


context.configure(
    url=URL,
    target_metadata=target_metadata,
    literal_binds=True,
    dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    user_module_prefix='sa.'
)

with context.begin_transaction():
    context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
connectable = create_engine(URL)

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        user_module_prefix='sa.'
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

my db.py file:

```
import sqlalchemy
import databases
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
ORMAR_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://admin:admin@localhost/fa_naesmi"

Base = declarative_base()
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
database = databases.Database(ORMAR_DATABASE_URL)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(ORMAR_DATABASE_URL)
```

and my `models.py`:

```
import datetime
import ormar
from typing import Optional
from db import database, metadata, Base


class MainMeta(Base, ormar.ModelMeta):
    metadata = metadata
    database = database


class Category(Base, ormar.Model):
    class Meta(MainMeta):
        pass

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=100)
```

after using `alembic revision -m "first"`, it doesn't migrate my models.

```
revision = '9176fb20d67a'
down_revision = '9159cff21eb5'
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

def upgrade():
    pass


def downgrade():
    pass
```

I already wrote in console `alembic revision --autogenerate -m "razraz"` and it creates alembic database tables, but migrations still not working.

Comment: by the way about this, it migrates only the models of the main directory, does not look at the subfolders where other models are also located.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is caused by usage of `declarative_base()` from `sqlalchemy`.

`Sqlalchemy` consists of two main parts:

- `ORM` - which is a object relational mapping part with Models, relations, queries etc.
- `core` - which is much more 'raw' and basic and in general it's related to table and columns creation, as well as queries generation (joins, where clause etc.)

In `ormar` only the latter is used and you cannot apply any concept from the `ORM` part. In fact `ormar` is kind of (simplified by `async` and `pydantic` based) equivalent of the `ORM` part.

That means that you cannot inherit from `Base` <- that's the orm part I mentioned.

So your sample should look something like following snippets:

alembic .env

```py
from logging.config import fileConfig
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

from db import ORMAR_DATABASE_URL
from models import metadata # adjust path if needed
from alembic import context
import sys, os

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
config = context.config

fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# note how it's 'raw' metadata not the one attached to Base as there is no Base
target_metadata = metadata
URL = ORMAR_DATABASE_URL


def run_migrations_offline():


context.configure(
    url=URL,
    target_metadata=target_metadata,
    literal_binds=True,
    dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    user_module_prefix='sa.'
)

with context.begin_transaction():
    context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
connectable = create_engine(URL)

with connectable.connect() as connection:
    context.configure(
        connection=connection,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        user_module_prefix='sa.'
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

db.py file:

```py
import sqlalchemy
import databases
ORMAR_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://admin:admin@localhost/fa_naesmi"

# note lack of declarative_base
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
database = databases.Database(ORMAR_DATABASE_URL)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(ORMAR_DATABASE_URL)
```

models.py:

```py
import datetime
import ormar
from typing import Optional
from db import database, metadata


# you cannot subclass Base class thats ORM part
class MainMeta(ormar.ModelMeta):
    metadata = metadata
    database = database


class Category(ormar.Model):
    class Meta(MainMeta):
        pass

    id: int = ormar.Integer(primary_key=True)
    name: str = ormar.String(max_length=100)
```

Disclaimer: I'm creator of `ormar` - if you have more questions or trouble with getting it to work let me know here. If that solves you issue remember to mark answer as accepted.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes! it worked! Thanks!
My main mistake was that since ormar uses sqlalchemy under the hood, it will work on ormar itself. I want to thank you for creating this beautiful orm! it is very easy to use and not only! I have a big project ahead of me on this orm!
and I would like to ask about the integration of graphql into ormar, are there any sources on this topic? I can't find it on the net. found on sqlalchemy but now I doubt that it will work. Or is it not related to orm but specifically to the framework?

Comment: No the ones for sqlalchemy won't work since you probably found graphene related info, and graphene won't work as it is a sync framework, you would have to use tartiflette or something else with async support. But there is no "helper" for any library/orm I think as of now

Comment: The key point for me was that we must import the models definitions themselves, because they actually "populate" the metadata. If you just import the metadata object without the models, it's empty, and the revisions are either empty or inverted (trying to drop tables instead of creating them).